# How do I point a domain name to a specific URL

Tags: .htaccess, dns, a-records

I have a website that every customer can have a personal profile page. A sample page address is :

http://www.goonagoon.net/index.php?mod=goonagoon&act=9&id=94a6t2x2p2z2e36424u56403f3d4y2m5

and I want to point a domain name to this specific url. For example when visiting www.mycustomer.com it shows the content of the above address (without changing the address).
How can I do this?